# What makes a CSS question opinion based or not?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Since CSS is about the aesthetical layout of a web page, I guess it's easy to ask opinion based questions.

I guess that asking about reusability of some CSS code would not be opinion-based.

On the opposite side of the spectrum a question along the lines of *is this layout nice?* would be opinion based.

But I guess there are questions in the middle:

- Is this layout captivating?
- Does this layout prompt the user to continue navigate on the site?
- Does this layout attract CSS enthusiast because of its amazing tricks?

I would say that these are probably closer to be opinion-based than not.

On the other hand, making a website appearance nice is the target of CSS, so all idioms that this language uses must be based on objective, measurable properties. Better, they should be based on the measurable (at least in a statistical sense) relation between those properties/layouts that CSS allows and the reaction in the user.

And this makes me think some of those question are a little bit less opinion-based.

Is there any guidance in this sense?

Comment: Whether layout is captivating or not is a UX problem, not a code one.

Answer (score 4):

## All questions on Code Review are opinion based

One of the requirements of posting on Code Review is allowing a reviewer to comment on *anything*.

> **Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?**
>
> Feel free to call attention to specific areas you are concerned about (performance, formatting, etc). However, any aspect of the code posted is fair game for feedback and criticism.
> — [help center / on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

A lot of feedback *is* opinion based. I've had people complain I've put points in my answer in the wrong order because *the commenter has a different opinion on what's right*. If you look at some users, you can see following established standards *is an opinion*. For example many Python users on Stack Exchange don't follow PEP 8.

If you're asking if your question is off-topic, for "opinion-based", then almost certainly not. I've only seen one question with legitimate close votes for "opinion based". However our "any and all" rule is a double edged sword, as reviewers *are not required* to answer any questions you have.

I suggest you just roll the dice.